# Is there a way in Dojo to find all widget descendants in a DOM element?

Tags: dojo

Is there a way in Dojo to find all widget descendants in a DOM element? I used the example below it will only list the children of the  element, in this case any widgets that are children of the document object, but not all the descendants or nested widgets. Hopefully that's clear.

```
var widgets = dijit.findWidgets(dojo.doc);
dojo.forEach(widgets, function(w) {
    console.log(w);
});
```

I could just write my own recursive function but I want to make sure I'm not missing out on a Dojo method which already does this.

Many thanks

Comment: just to be clear, you want a function to get all of the widgets below a domNode, including those widgets which are nested in other widgets?

Comment: @screenm0nkey, did you ever end up finding a solution to this?  I need this exact functionality too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>Hmm, `dijit.findWidgets(parentWidget.domNode)` ?</s>

**Edit** Oh, now I nee findWidgets doesn't search recursively.

I checked the dijit.findWidgets source code and all it does is check for nodes with a `widgetid` attribute that are represented in the dijit registry. The following version uses dojo.query to do this same search recursively:

```js
function findEvenTheNestedWidgets(innitialNode){
    return dojo.query("[widgetid]", innitialNode)
    .map(dijit.byNode)
   .filter(function(wid){ return wid;}) //filter invalid widget ids that yielded undefined
}
```

Comment: Hey missingno. Was that a guess? I don't think there is a dojo.findWidgets method.

Comment: oops, i meant dijit... The important part is that you can choose the widget's domNode to start the search instead of searching all widgets in the document.

Comment: But that still only gives me the children directly under that domNode, not the widgets nested in inside the children and the children's children etc.

Comment: I'm guessing there is not such a function unless someone would have answered by now. I meant to +1 you for helping but accidentally selected it as the right answer;)

Comment: Check the updated version. I think it actually worthy of the green checkmark now that I did some research :P

Comment: is this solution still necessary for the latest dojo build?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you should ask a separate question for that (just make sure to link to this one so noone closes it as a duplicate).