# Dojo toggle selectableLegend

Tags: jquery, charts, dojo

I am looking for a better way to toggle Dojo Legends.  Unfortunately they are not straight checkboxes, so the only way I got it working was to trigger a click event on the dojo checkbox

Currently I use something like the following:

```
$('.dojoxLegendText').each(function(index) {
  var lblText = $.trim($(this).text());
  //if statement here to determine if legend should be toggled
  $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

My problem with this is the scrolling of the page whilst the legends are toggled.  It is not very pleasing for the users.

Anyone have a better alternative, or solution to prevent the scrolling?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code: Change: `var lblText = $.(trim($(this).text());` to: `var lblText = $.trim($(this).text());`

Comment: Thank you.  Have now edited.  Typed it wrong in this window.

Answer (score 0):

They are dijit checkboxes. Try getting them using

> firstcheckbox=dijit.byId("dijit_form_CheckBox_0");
>   secondcheckbox=dijit.byId("dijit_form_CheckBox_1");

The "dijit_form_CheckBox_0" represents the id of the widget. Dojo gives them
out automaticaly , so try to hover over a checkbox using firebug to take a look
at the id.

You can uncheck them using:

> firstcheckbox.set("checked",false);

The better way to get the widgets is to use dojo to get the widgets inside your legend.
Take a look here for that:

[Is there a way in Dojo to find all widget descendants in a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886904/is-there-a-way-in-dojo-to-find-all-widget-descendants-in-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 0):

i've made a function called toggleSeries you can use to toggle the Legends / checkboxes on and off:

> ```
> function toggleSeries (legend,num) { // legend = SelectableLegend
>
> dojo.query("*",legend.legends[num])[0].click();
>
> dijit.findWidgets(legend.legends[num])[0]._onClick(); }
> ```

Here is a jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/luciancd/92Dzv/17/

For more information regarding that function take a look at my lated post on:

[Hiding a series by default in a spider plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739176/hiding-a-series-by-default-in-a-spider-plot/14830538#14830538)

Lucian