# Hiding a series by default in a spider plot

Tags: dojo, graphing, dojox.charting

I have a spider plot in using the graphing library of Dojo defined like this:

```
require([
    "dojox/charting/Chart", 
    "dojox/charting/themes/Claro", 
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Spider", 
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip", 
    "dojox/charting/widget/SelectableLegend", 
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default"
    ], function (Chart, theme, Spider, Tooltip, Legend, Default) {
        var chart = new Chart(element).setTheme(theme).addPlot("default", {
            type: Spider,
            radius: 200,
            fontColor: "black",
            labelOffset: "-20"
        });
        var colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "teal", 
                    "maroon", "olive", "lime", "aqua", "fuchsia"];
        $.each(factors, function (index, factor) {
            chart.addAxis(factor.name, {
                 type: Default,
                 min: factor.min,
                 max: factor.max
             });
        });
        $.each(presets, function (pIndex, preset) {
            var data = [];
            $.each(factors, function (fIndex, factor) {
                 data[factor.name] = preset.values[fIndex];
            });
            chart.addSeries(preset.short, data, {
                 fill: colors[pIndex % colors.length]
            });
        });
        new Tooltip(chart, "default");
        chart.render();
        new Legend({
            chart: chart,
            horizontal: false
        }, $(element).next(".legend")[0]);
    });
```

I add a series for every member of an array called `presets` and I use a selectable legend that lets the user turn them on or off as they want. However, what I can't seem to find in the docs is how to start a series in the unselected, not visible state? What I ideally want to do is cap the number of series visible when the page loads because in some cases I have up to 14 presets and it just looks a mess until the user deselects a bunch. So I'd like to have, say, every preset above the first 5 be hidden at the start.

Here's a crude [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92Dzv/) I've knocked to demonstrate. What I want is to have some of the series unselected when the plot is first displayed.

**Update**: I tried adding this after adding my series:

```
var checkboxes = $(".dijitCheckBoxInput").each((index, elem) => {
     if (index > 4) {
         elem.click();
     }
});
```

Which works, but seems very fragile. If they change the class assigned to checkboxes, it'll break. Also, it prohibits me using more than one set of dojo checkboxes because I don't have a good way to tell the difference. (Note, the IDs of the checkboxes added by the `SelectableLegend` are `dijit_form_CheckBox_0`, `dijit_form_CheckBox_1`, etc, which also gives no useful information as to what they are related to). I thought I might be able to use the legend placeholder div as a way to select the descendant checkboxes, but it appears that Dojo replaces the placeholder entirely with a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i looked into the dojo code and found the area in which the shapes are toggled on & off whitin the SelectableLegend.js :

> ```
>           var legendCheckBox = query(".dijitCheckBox", legend)[0];
>           hub.connect(legendCheckBox, "onclick", this, function(e){
>               this._toggle(shapes, i, legend.vanished, originalDyn, seriesName, plotName);
>               legend.vanished = !legend.vanished;
>               e.stopPropagation();
>           });
> ```

The toggling process is very complex and is based on many local attributes:

```
_toggle: function(shapes, index, isOff, dyn, seriesName, plotName){
            arrayUtil.forEach(shapes, function(shape, i){
                var startFill = dyn.fills[i],
                    endFill = this._getTransitionFill(plotName),
                    startStroke = dyn.strokes[i],
                    endStroke = this.transitionStroke;
                if(startFill){
                    if(endFill && (typeof startFill == "string" || startFill instanceof Color)){
                        fx.animateFill({
                            shape: shape,
                            color: {
                                start: isOff ? endFill : startFill,
                                end: isOff ? startFill : endFill
                            }
                        }).play();
                    }else{
                        shape.setFill(isOff ? startFill : endFill);
                    }
                }
                if(startStroke && !this.outline){
                    shape.setStroke(isOff ? startStroke : endStroke);
                }
            }, this);
        }
```

I tried also checking & unchecking the dijit/form/Checkbox in a legend manually, but that does not trigger the _toggle function in any case, even if you do a render() / fullrender() on the chart.

**With that in mind it seems that there is no other possibilty to toggle the series on and off than by firing the onclick events manually.**

To make your code less fragile, you could access the Checkbox widgets within the legend manually using:

> query(".dijitCheckBox", legend); // Should deliver an array containing
>   the widgets.

and triggering the onclick event on them. Their keynumber in the array should correspond to the order the series where added...

Dojo is a fine piece of work, please dont stop working with it !

Comment: I did see the `_toggle` code in `SelectableLegend` and thought there had to be an easier way. IMHO, it seems completely backwards. Surely the legend should just tell the series to hide itself and the series should be taking care of that part. Also, I'm not sure about using Dojo `query`, but I know from examining the DOM that SelectableLegend completely replaces the existing placeholder element with a table making it harder to find the thing again (I guess you could wrap your placeholder in another placeholder just for this purpose, but that seems a little silly).

Comment: Hi Matt, please notice that everything in dojox is experimental & and didnt make it into dojo or dijit yet. :-/

Source:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/index.html

Comment: Well in your link the `dojox/charting` library is listed as `mature`. I think the dojo charts are very attractive, but I'm finding dojo in general to be frustrating to use compared to, say, jQuery. The requirement to load modules asynchronously makes getting started awkward.

Comment: i agree that getting started with dojo isn't easy, but it's worth it. i am working on a big application and dojo allows me to keep the code of my plugins seperate from each other. the communication between them with dojo/topic helps me maintain the dependency very low. I use jquery too, it's good for selecting things, but it didnt help me ondeveloping a structured client-application...

Answer (score 1):

dojox/charting/Series has an attribute called dirty which according to the [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/charting/Series) is a "flag indicating whether or not this element needs to be rendered".

Alternately, if you are limiting the display of some series you can write a separate interface for adding them. For example, loop over the first 5. Then create a select box or list of check boxes with all entries and an onchange event that calls chart.addSeries.

Keeping a reference to each series you create will allow you to later call destroy() or destroyRecursive() on it if the user no longer wishes it displayed.

So while ideally you could toggle the display of these series, the worst case senerio is that you just add, destroy, and read based on some user input.

Using a [templated widget](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/templated/) will allow you to keep this interface and the chart tightly linked and support reuse.

BTW, consider using "dojo/_base/array" and "dojo/query" in place of the jquery

Comment: I may have to just `.addSeries` and remove them manually from a set of checkboxes (the `dirty` flag doesn't seem to do anything). It's really annoying that they don't have a simple way to do this. Using my own checkboxes will probably mean I then lose the highlighting ability when you mouse over the `SelectableLegend`. I'm using Dojo *only* for this spider graph (which is better than any other JS spider graph I've come across - which isn't saying much). I'm using jQuery, knockout and flot everywhere else and not looking to add more Dojo if I can help it.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code http://jsfiddle.net/92Dzv/18/

Here is the key to toogle.

```
dom.byId(le._cbs[0].id).click();
dom.byId(le._cbs[2].id).click();
```

Choose the index of your legend and set to `_cbs`.

By this way `le._cbs[0].id` you will get the real id of checkbox (that inside in the widget) and then just use `click()`

Note : `le` is came from here.

```
var le = new Legend({
                chart: chart,
                horizontal: false
             }, legend);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i've got it !

I found another way to access the checkboxes ! It's the same way dojo uses internally to connect the "toggle code" to the onclick event. First take a look at this from SelectableLegend.js (Lines 150 - 156):

> ```
>           //  toggle action
>           var legendCheckBox = query(".dijitCheckBox", legend)[0];
>           hub.connect(legendCheckBox, "onclick", this, function(e){
>               this._toggle(shapes, i, legend.vanished, originalDyn, seriesName, plotName);
>               legend.vanished = !legend.vanished;
>               e.stopPropagation();
>           });
> ```

It looks like they use the ".dijitCheckBox" class to find the checkbox dom element and connect to it using dojo/connect. Now based on that, i made this function:

> function toggleSeries (legend,num) {
>
> dojo.query("*",legend.legends[num])[0].click();
>
> dijit.findWidgets(legend.legends[num])[0]._onClick();   }

It doesn't use any class definition (because of the *****) and it accesses the areas where the checkboxes are from within the SelectableLegend. It needs the SelectableLegend and the number of the series you want to deactivate as parameters. Here the jsfiddle example with this function & hiding all 4 of your series with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/luciancd/92Dzv/17/

Also please notice the "onDomReady" Option in jsfiddle, without it: doesnt work in IE.
And the ready function within the code !

Lucian